# jquery xml select

Tags: jquery, xml, selector

How to select items whose sub-tag key's text starts with '001'?

```
<root>
    <item>
        <key>001001</key>
        <text>thanks</text>
    </item>
    <item>
        <key>001002</key>
        <text>very</text>
    </item>
    <item>
        <key>002001</key>
        <text>much</text>
    </item>
</root>



$(xml).find("item>[filter string]").each(function()
{
    alert(this);
});
```

Comment: Do you control the XML schema? Promoting the children to attributes might work better (`<item key="001001" text="thanks">`). Even just the `key` if there exists a lot more under an `<item>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) in this case:

```
$(xml).find("item").filter(function() {
  return $(this).find("key").text().indexOf('001') === 0;
}).each(function() {
    alert(this);
});
```

This filters the items by those having a key element who's text starts with `001`.  If you could modify the schema at all though, this would be much faster...searching in the children for the filter is a bit expensive overall if you're dealing with many items.

[Jake](https://stackoverflow.com/users/132047/jake-wharton)'s comment suggestion is a good one if it's an option, if an item had attributes instead of inner elements, you could do it much simpler with the [attribute starts-with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/), like this:

```
$(xml).find("item[key^=001]").each(function() { alert(this); });
```