# Selecting Nodes in xml with an specific attribute with jQuery

Tags: jquery, xml, css-selectors, rdf

after reading [jquery xml select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2672176/jquery-xml-select) I wanted to do something similar with this rdf/xml:

```
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
 <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://someURI/999">
  <dc:relation rdf:resource="http://www.someURI/888" />
 </rdf:Description>
 <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.someURI/001">
  <dc:relation rdf:resource="http://www.someURI/987/777"/>
 </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

I want to select the node with the attribute "rdf:about" ending with 001. I tried:

```
var node = $(xml).find("rdf:Description[rdf:about$=001]");
```

But it wont work. It returns the whole thing document. 
Any ideas?

Edit: Corrected spelling error. Doesn't change the problem, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uhm... I think is an escape problem. Try to use

```
var node = $(xml).find("rdf\\:Description[rdf\\:about$=001]");
```

Comment: Sorry tanathos, I have been working on this (way to long). I really don't understand why this doesn't work for me. The longer I stare at it, the more I am convinced that it is correct and my error has to be somewhere else. I'll keep looking and use a workaround for now. Thanks for your help- sorry for the late accept.

Answer (score 0):

Check your spelling. It's `rdf:Description` with an upper-case `D`. In XML, the case is significant.

Comment: Yes and no. There is a spelling error, but once corrected I still see the same behavior. Which made me thinking: Is my handling of the return value incorrect? I do that like so: 
`var node = $(rdfDoc).find("rdf:Description[rdf:about$=001]");`

Comment: tanathos got it right, as far as I can see. The colon must be escaped. There's nothing wrong with the variable assignment, it's best jQuery style ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Run into similar problem. For me dropping the namespace worked.
So I would try something like: `$(rdfDoc).find("Description[about$=001]");`
Not 100% sure about the attribute cause I was only trying to obtain node.